# How to prepocess images for a classification task?

Tags: image-processing, image-classification

I got the task to classify images (binary). There are images containing bicycles and images containing no bicycles. I do not have much data so I'm looking for an option (filter, etc.) that emphasize the characteristics of a bicycle in a picture. I already tried laplace and canny filter getting rather bad results when feeding the features to a classifier. Any ideas?